# Query based on three database tables always returns zero results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with three tables in it:

places:

```
id    |  name  |  latitude  | longitude  |
------|--------|------------|------------|
1     | place1 | 11.123456  | 76.123456  |
------|--------|------------|------------|
2     | place2 | 23.123456  | 65.123456  |
etc ...
```

categorized_places:

```
id    | place_id | cat_id |
------|----------|--------|
1     |    1     |   2    |
------|----------|--------|
2     |    2     |   1    |
etc ...
```

places_visited:

```
id    | user_name | user_email | place_id |
------|-----------|------------|----------|
1     |   user_1  | x@mail.com |    2     |
------|-----------|------------|----------|
2     |   user_2  | y@mail.com |    2     |
```

There's also a fourth named categories, but it's not important in this.

I'm trying to filter the places from the places-table to show the user the nearest place, that he/she has not yet visited.

$cur_cat is set on the previous page, where the user selects which kind of place he/she would like to visit.

$cur_user and $cur_user_email are based on $_SESSION variables

$max_lat, $max_lon, $min_lat and $min_lon are based on the users current position

I'm using this code in php (with PDO), but it always returns zero results:

```
$get_places = $db->prepare("
    SELECT
        places.id,
        places.name,
        places.latitude,
        places.longitude
    FROM
        places,
        categorized_places,
        places_visited
    WHERE
        places.id = categorized_places.place_id
        AND categorized_places.cat_id = '$cur_cat'
        AND places.latitude <= '$max_lat'
        AND places.latitude >= '$min_lat'
        AND places.longitude <= '$max_lon'
        AND places.longitude >= '$min_lon'
        AND places_visited.user_name = '$cur_user'
        AND places_visited.user_email = '$cur_user_email'
        AND places.id != places_visited.place_id
");
$get_places->execute();
```

The code always shows 0 results and throws no error. I've also made sure, that the places are not already in the places_visited table.

I've stared at this for so very long now, and I just can't figure out the error.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is doing inner joins.  So, it can only return places that the user has visited.  No way that it can return places that a user hasn't visited.  Before proceeding further, here is a simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `from` clause.  ANSI standard explicit `JOIN` syntax has been around for over two decades, and you should use it.  In fact, in this case, you need it, because you need an outer join:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.latitude, p.longitude
FROM places p INNER JOIN
     categorized_places cp
     ON p.id = cp.place_id LEFT JOIN
     places_visited pv
     ON pv.place_id = p.id AND
        pv.user_name = '$cur_user' AND
        pv.user_email = '$cur_user_email'          
WHERE cp.cat_id = '$cur_cat' AND
      p.latitude <= '$max_lat' AND
      p.latitude >= '$min_lat' AND
      p.longitude <= '$max_lon' AND
      p.longitude >= '$min_lon' AND
      pv.place_id IS NULL;
```

What this does is it matches the conditions to all the places visited, using an outer join.  Then the condition `pv.place_id IS NULL` chooses the ones that have not been visited.  Note that the conditions on the `places_visited` table go in the `ON` clause.  The conditions on the other two tables remain in the `WHERE` clause.  In general, when using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, the filters on the first table stay in the `WHERE` clause.  The filters on the second table go in the `ON` clause.

I also introduced table aliases.  These help make queries easier to write and to read.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm still a beginner at MySQL, so I have a lot to learn :)